# Using YouTube iframe API, how to display the full screen control hiding the volume control

Tags: youtube-api

I'm developping a web page using YouTube iframe API. I want the full screeen control displayed on the screen while I do not want the volume control on the screen. Is my requirement possible to achieve?

The current code does not work.

```
    playerVars: 
      {   
          'fs':1,
          'controls':0
      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct by setting the `fs to 1` to view the fullscreen control. However, if you set the `controls to 0`, it will also affect the fullscreen control. Because the player will load immediately and the controls will gone. You can try the different [player parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Parameters) here in this [YouTube Player Demo](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo). Just click the show player parameter to view the different options.